# Can you issue a warning to users before they update to the latest version of your app in the google play store?

Tags: java, android, database, google-play

I made a mistake on backwards compatibility with database structure and general code. If users update to the new version, they'll lose all their data, but only if they update. If they don't update, they'll be fine, and can save everything.

You may be thinking, don't release the update and fix the problem. The update is massive and has changed everything. There's no way to do this.

If I am allowed to warn them before they upgrade their app, everything will be better. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: does your app have push notifications? you could warn them by sending them an in-app notification that way

Comment: How can you send the warning? Does the previous version provide some features (like firebase)  to do it? Block the update in google play and push a new version.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo - No, it doesn't have push notifications. That's a good idea. The barrier would need to be stronger between the users and an upgrade because a notification could be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll back your update on the playstore, fix the issues and roll new update out.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to know what happens in the meantime, and how they can prevent every user from updating the app before the roll back takes effect

Comment: Rollback wouldn't help since the compatibility issues with the new code are extremely complicated. The old code and the new code. The old database structure and the new database structure. I just messed up. They're data is safe with the old version, and if they were prompted, they could take a multitude of screenshots of the data they want to keep.

Comment: You cannot prevent users from updating the app. But you can write migrations for the database - you can even write migrations if you moved from clean SQLlite to room. And they may be complicated - but you ca always write a migration. Except when you moved from sql to realm - in this case you screwed...

Comment: Not this time. I need a hard message to users before they update their app. If this doesn't exist, it should. I may just not release an update ever, and abandon the app and maybe rewrite it in dart/flutter under a new name. It's the only way I can 100% guarantee no data lose.